# Android Emulator is launching inside Android Studio but not showing up in the device tab

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

The new Android Studio 4.1 update brings the emulator inside Android Studio IDE.

After Enabling the feature, the emulator does launch inside the IDE but doesn't show up in the `device` tab. And the Emulator is also not responding to mouse taps.

---

This image would help you get an idea about the problem.

[image]

---

And when the emulator is launched traditionally all works just fine.

Comment: The new update resolved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tacked this by doing a cold boot of the AVD from the avd manager.

*ps: check that you have enabled this feature from the settings menu.*

---

## Steps:

**1) Open AVD Manager.**
**2) click the down-arrow from the actions tab of the AVD you want.**
[image]
**3) Then click on 'Cold Boot Now'**
[image]

Answer (score 26):

You can turn off this feature by: File >> Setting >> Emulator >> uncheck "Launch in a took window"
[image]

Comment: I don't want to turn off this feature,

Comment: On Mac it's Android Studio  >> Preferences >> Tools

Answer (score 2):

Try to this steps.

- Open AVD Manager
- Remove defined device
- Click invalidates Cahe / Restart
- Close Android studio
- Restart your computer
- Open Android studio
- Create a new device at AVD Manager

Then click play.

It will be work fine.